# Normal subgroup such that $(|H|,[H:G])=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $H,K\triangleleft G$ such that $(|H|,[H:G])=1=(|K|,[K:G])$. Prove that $H=K$.

Hint: what happens to $K$ in $G/H$?

I don't urdestand the hint. Can someone give me a hint to get the hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the question correctly?  This is not true as written.  Take $G=H\times K$, with $H$ of order $2$ and $K$ of order $3$. Then $(|H|,[G:H]) = (2,3) = 1 = (3,2) = (|K|,[G:K])$, but certainly $H\neq K$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $(|K|,[H:G])=1=(|H|,[K:G])?$ Under this constraint, it's easy to show the image of $K$ in the projection $G\twoheadrightarrow G/H$ is $0$, thus $K\leqslant H$. Similarly we have $H\leqslant K$.